# Method Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint::unsignedBidInteger does not exist

Tags: php, laravel, database, migrate

```
PS C:\xampp\htdocs\learning\laragon\lavue> php artisan migrate
Migrating: 2022_07_17_042348_create_transaction_details_table

   BadMethodCallException 

  Method Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint::unsignedBidInteger does not exist.

  at C:\xampp\htdocs\learning\laragon\lavue\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Macroable\Traits\Macroable.php:113
    109▕      */
    110▕     public function __call($method, $parameters)
    111▕     {
    112▕         if (! static::hasMacro($method)) {
  ➜ 113▕             throw new BadMethodCallException(sprintf(
    114▕                 'Method %s::%s does not exist.', static::class, $method
    115▕             ));
    116▕         }
    117▕

  1
```

error in terminal

C:\xampp\htdocs\learning\laragon\lavue\database\migrations\2022_07_17_042348_create_transaction_details_table.php:18
Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint::__call()

```
  2   C:\xampp\htdocs\learning\laragon\lavue\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Schema\Builder.php:256
      Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration@anonymous\C:\xampp\htdocs\learning\laragon\lavue\database\migrations\2022_07_17_042348_create_transaction_details_table.php:7$b5::{closure}()
```

this my php migration

```
    <?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

return new class extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('transaction_details', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->unsignedBidInteger('transaction_id');
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('book_id');
            $table->integer('qty');
            $table->timestamps();

            $table->foreign('transaction_id')->references('id')->on('transactions');
            $table->foreign('book_id')->references('id')->on('books');

        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
public function down()
{
    Schema::dropIfExists('transaction_details');
}
```

};

When i put php artisan migration sees an error like above

Comment: unsignedBigInteger should be not unsignedBidInteger. $table->unsignedBidInteger('transaction_id');

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a typo in your migration file on 'transaction_id' declaration.

Your migration file should be like this. Check the line with the comment.

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

return new class extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('transaction_details', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('transaction_id'); // instead of $table->unsignedBidInteger('transaction_id')
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('book_id');
            $table->integer('qty');
            $table->timestamps();

            $table->foreign('transaction_id')->references('id')->on('transactions');
            $table->foreign('book_id')->references('id')->on('books');

        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
public function down()
{
    Schema::dropIfExists('transaction_details');
}
```

Kindly read [this](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/migrations#column-method-unsignedBigInteger).

Comment: ah i forget that thanks for help